# Android FontFamily support for AppCompat

Tags: android, android-styles, android-appcompat, android-fonts

Does anyone know how to overcome the issue of font family support for the AppCompat theme?

I used AppCompat v7 Library in Android that handles well on ActionBar issues but
the attribute mentioned below is not available in the android values/style.xml default folder.

Which is why i am unable to customize Edittext control.

`<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>`

What would be the alternative way to use the custom font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use custom font in my application.

To custom the title of action bar you need to use the next code.

```
private void changeSizeTitle() {

    fontTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/helvetical.ttf");// font in the file assets/fonts
    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
            "android");
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    yourTextView.setTypeface(fontTitle);
    yourTextView.setTextSize(20);
}
```

be careful when you restart the activity, you need to call again that method.